# StringBuilder и большой текст

Tags: android, строки, android-sdk

Есть программа, которая считывает с БД текст из 5 млн. символов, и выводит их по частям на несколько страниц.
Есть метод, который обрабатывает этот текст, считывает сколько текста может вместиться в видимую часть экрана и возвращает лист страниц

```
    pages.add(mSpannableStringBuilder.subSequence(startOffset, endOffset));
```

Проблема в том, что при считывании текста и присвоение его stringbuilder`у занимает много времени(7-10 сек).
Мог бы поделить текст на несколько частей запихнуть в List и передать list в publishProgress(). Но мне необходимо передать сначала  ВЕСЬ ТЕКСТ в  StringBuilder , потом чтобы из этого текста метод split() распределял текст на несколько страниц.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в моем случае как лучше обработать такой большой текст?  Как в onProgressUpdate передавать текст по частям, если метод onProgressUpdate срабатывает только,  после операции  `stringBuilder.append(modelList.get(i).getDetails());`, которая занимает (7-10 сек)?

```
    protected final List<CharSequence> doInBackground(List<CharSequence>... voids) {
        SqliteDbHelper dbHelper;
        ArrayList<BookModel> modelList;

        dbHelper = new SqliteDbHelper(context);
        modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        dbHelper.openDataBase();
        modelList = dbHelper.getDetails();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <modelList.size() ; i++) {
            stringBuilder.append(modelList.get(i).getDetails());
        }
       // final Spanned bodyText =
          //      getFormattedBookText(String.valueOf(modelList.get(0).getDetails()+modelList.get(1).getDetails()));

        int desiredDimen;
       
        if (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels
                > context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels) {
            int dif = (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels -
                    context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels) / 2;
            desiredDimen = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - dif;

        } else {
            int dif = (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels -
                    context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels) / 2;
            desiredDimen = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - 300;

        }

        final PageSplitter pageSplitter =
                new PageSplitter(desiredDimen,
                        desiredDimen * 2,
                        1f,
                        1f);



        pageSplitter.append(stringBuilder);

        TextPaint mPaintDetail = new TextPaint();
        mPaintDetail.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        mPaintDetail.setShadowLayer(2.0f, 0f, 2.0f, Color.DKGRAY);
        mPaintDetail.setTextSize(10 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        mPaintDetail.setAntiAlias(true);

        pageSplitter.split(mPaintDetail);

        publishProgress(pageSplitter.getPages());
        //Log.d("vadsf", "fav" + delegate.);
        return delegate.splitBookDoInBackground();
    }


public class PageSplitter {
    private final int pageWidth;
    private final int pageHeight;
    private final float lineSpacingMultiplier;
    private final float lineSpacingExtra;
    private final List<CharSequence> pages = new ArrayList<>();
    private final SpannableStringBuilder mSpannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    public PageSplitter(int pageWidth,
                        int pageHeight,
                        float lineSpacingMultiplier,
                        float lineSpacingExtra) {
        this.pageWidth = pageWidth;
        this.pageHeight = pageHeight;
        this.lineSpacingMultiplier = lineSpacingMultiplier;
        this.lineSpacingExtra = lineSpacingExtra;

    }

    public void append(CharSequence charSequence) {

        mSpannableStringBuilder.append(charSequence);

    }

    public void split(TextPaint textPaint) {

        StaticLayout staticLayout = new StaticLayout(
                mSpannableStringBuilder,
                textPaint,
                pageWidth,
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                lineSpacingMultiplier,
                lineSpacingExtra,
                false
        );

        int startLine = 0;
        while (startLine < staticLayout.getLineCount()) {
            int startLineTop = staticLayout.getLineTop(startLine);
            int endLine = staticLayout.getLineForVertical(startLineTop + pageHeight);
            int endLineBottom = staticLayout.getLineBottom(endLine);
            int lastFullyVisibleLine;
            if (endLineBottom > startLineTop + pageHeight)
                lastFullyVisibleLine = endLine - 1;
            else
                lastFullyVisibleLine = endLine;
            int startOffset = staticLayout.getLineStart(startLine);
            int endOffset = staticLayout.getLineEnd(lastFullyVisibleLine);
            pages.add(mSpannableStringBuilder.subSequence(startOffset, endOffset));
            Log.d("vasdf", String.valueOf(pages.get(0)));

            startLine = lastFullyVisibleLine + 1;
        }

    }


    public List<CharSequence> getPages() {
        return pages;
    }


}
```

Comment: конечно не понятно как оно работает и что такое i в modelList.get(i)? Думаю вам надо как то показать более или менее код который будет работать и ошибка будет вовсе не тут

Comment: Вы уверены что только операция `append` занимает 10 сек? Может вы имели ввиду весь метод `doInBackground`? Тогда ваш код можно оптимизировать - создать экземпляр хелпера и открыть базу заранее, далее переиспользовать этот экземпляр, а не открывать при каждом обращении. Потом получить из базы **одну** нужную строку, а не выбирать целый список, чтобы взять из него один элемент с индексом `i`.

Comment: Перепроверил , не append занимает 10 сек, не при создании страниц (фрагментов) около 800

Сначала в классе Async заполняется stringBuilder, а потом уже этот stringBuilder принимает метод append класса PageSplitter, в методе в котором заполняется SpannableStringBuilder. Это все загружается моментально. 

Как я понял, загрузка идет там, где обрабатывается текст, в методе split. Добавил Полный код

Comment: Но суть задачи не меняется.. Мне все еще нужно как-то передавать текст в метод append класса PageSplitter по частям, и потом полученный обработанный текст передавать в progressUpdate

Comment: _Как я понял, загрузка идет там_ - зачем гадать и тратить время впустую (что если не там), запустите профайлер и смотрите где у вас нагрузка. В качестве пробного костыля можете попробовать публиковать части на месте этой строки: `pages.add(mSpannableStringBuilder.subSequence(startOffset, endOffset));`